# VSCode Extension User Input Passward

Tags: input, terminal, vscode-extensions

I am trying to develop a VSCode Extension that requires user passward to run a command on the terminal. I have tried this but it throws an irrelevant error.

```
const readline = require('readline');
const reader = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

reader.question("Enter: ", passward=>{
    reader.close();
});
```

Clearly, I am placing it wrong or something else because it runs fine in an individual node js file. I am placing it inside of `registercommand`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *run a command in the Terminal* you mean that some command should be displayed/added in VS Code terminal, then you should look at the **Terminal API** in VS Code.

There is a sample in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/terminal-sample, and it will probably help you better understand how to integrate with VS Code terminal.

Hope this helps